# How i can resolve the warning of unknown publisher in Windows exe file

Tags: windows

Not getting any way to set or remove the publisher name from windows. I don't want to solve by security setting. If any other solution please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are other options, but the only ones I know are local security policies (open via Start -> run: `gpedit.msc`):

> Local Computer Policy -> User Configuration -> Administrative
>   Templates -> Windows Components -> Attachment Manager

Low risk file types:
Enter the file types you want (e.g. `.exe`)

Or via [registry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/19/how-to-bypass-the-security-warning-unknown-publisher-with-the-checkbox-always-ask-before-opening-this-file.aspx):

> Registry keys:
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies]
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
>
> "LowRiskFileTypes"=".exe;.vbs;.msi"
>
> "DefaultFileTypeRisk"=dword:00001808
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
>
> "SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001

Comment: from where i get local computer policy.

Comment: start -> run: gpedti.msc, for example

Comment: sorry, typo and too late to edit: gpedit.msc

Comment: @Lenniey - You should update your answer so its specific.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right.